# Authorization_IdentityNotFound on Microsoft Graph API request

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to develop an app in my enterprise and I've followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds) to get access to the AD users information. Meaning:

1. I created an app in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/
2. I set `User.Read.All` in **Application Permissions** and `User.Read` in **Delegated Permissions**

With this done I'm able to successfully login (Azure AD OAuth2 with `https://graph.microsoft.com/` as resource and `User.Read` as scope) and get a correct response from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`.

3. Ask the Admin for the Delegated Permissions

With this, my admin can see in the [azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/) that my App has both permissions consented by himself.

This is working because I asked a coworker to log in and I could get a correct response from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` even though he wasn't even prompted to consent this (Before the admin consenting the permissions the user was prompted)

4. Request a token from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token` with `client_credentials` as a `response_type`
5. Receive the token!
6. Do a GET request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` and receive:

   ```
   {
       "error": {
           "code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
           "message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established.",
           "innerError": {
               "request-id": "b2d9ec62-0b65-44eb-9e0f-4aec52b45750",
               "date": "2017-03-22T19:19:48"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Furthermore, doing a request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Current authenticated context is not valid for this request",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "047e2ba9-a858-45fc-a0dd-124e1db503f3",
      "date": "2017-03-22T19:39:25"
    }
  }
}
```

Which leads me to believe that Microsoft knows this token and knows it is not impersonating any user.

I've been looking for documentation on Azure AD and Microsoft Graph authentication but I only find blog posts and all seem outdated (although most features are in preview).
If you could point me in the right direction I would thank you.

I've also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538845/authorization-identitynotfound-error-ms-graph-api) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151346/authorization-identitynotfound-error-while-accessing-graph-api) similar questions on SO but they all remain unanswered.

**Update, after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42965398/4470542)**

Thank you, Dan,
I've used my organization domain name and I'm also able to get a token.

Now the response from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/` is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "3f190b47-73f5-4b29-96f9-54ed3dbc3137",
      "date": "2017-03-23T11:07:15"
    }
  }
}
```

Which makes no sense because in the azure portal I have `User.Read.All` as Application Permission (already consented by the admin).

I think the problem is with the request for the token, that returns successfully no matter the `scope` I send, even if I made one up.

For Example:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<domain>/oauth2/token

client_id:*******
client_secret:*******
resource:https://graph.microsoft.com/
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:Foo.Bar
```

Returns:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3599",
  "ext_expires_in": "0",
  "expires_on": "1490271617",
  "not_before": "1490267717",
  "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
  "access_token": *****
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had two problems, both not covered documentation:

- For **client credentials**, if the app belongs to a work or school (organization) context then for `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token` replace `common` with a tenantId or domain name (thanks to [Dan Kershaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4092015/dan-kershaw-msft))
- For `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` or `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}` you need `Directory.Read.All` permission.

**Note**:

- `User.Read.All` is relevant for Microsoft to stop requesting permissions (delegation) to the user when you ask for `User.Read` in the OAuth workflow. Check this and other Permission related issues in the [Release Notes](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/overview/release_notes#microsoft-graph-permissions).
- I've added this [issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/990) to the Microsoft Graph Docs!

Comment: Thanks.  The Directory service itself does not support User.Read.All application permission.  We are fixing that.  Unfortunately our docs aren't detailed enough about whether the pre-req permissions are delegated or application permissions.  For reading users, Directory currently supports User.Read.All as a delegated permission, but not as an application permission.  Thanks for filing the doc issue.  I'll respond there also.

Answer (score 1):

The `/me` segment is a shortcut or alias for the currently signed-in user. The request to `/me` will never work with an application token, because it doesn't contain any user context (or signed in user) - and hence the error.  We might be able to improve this error though ;)

I *believe* when using the client credentials flow, you need to specify the actual tenant that you want a token for.

If you're app is performing this operation in a work or school (organization) context then for `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token` replace `common` with a tenantId or domain name, and see if that works.

If you are following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds it looks like we might have a couple of doc bugs in there that we need to fix...

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the answer. I agree with ``/me``, I only used it to make a point. I've updated the question in light with your answer. Also, the docs end with a ``/v1.0/me/messages`` request (that makes no sense!!)

Comment: I've answered this question as I finally managed to solve the problem. If you want to update your answer according to mine and I will accept (the simple suggestion to use the domain name allowed me to debug :)) Tomorow I will clean my question so it can be a reference for others but I really think you should work on the docs.