# The identity of the calling application could not be established while I try to create a new user using Graph API In Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, postman, single-sign-on

An Application has been registered in Azure Active Directory and all the client IDs, client secrets, and tenant IDs have been created.

After I give User.ReadWrite, User.All and Directory.All accesses in both applications and delegated type on Microsoft graph API.

I tried using this API [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) to get bearer token using the request body:

clientID:{clientId},
clientSecret:{clientSecret},
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

After getting the bearer token with that I am not able to create a user using the below graph API
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users, I get this error.

"error": {
"code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
"message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established.",
}

Could anybody tell me how to create a new user using this API?
Could anybody tell me I was correct on authorization? If no tell me how to?

Comment: Could you please share the request body when creating a new user? Does the request to get users work? GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Comment: {
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "Pafasos",
  "mailNickname": "Pafasos",
  "userPrincipalName": "pafasos708@bodeem.com",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "smdksa@A19"
  }
}

@user2250152 could you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to give User.ReadWrite.All application permission to the application and grant admin consent .

[image]

And check if your application is registered as multi tenant application.

In that case give the correct target tenantId where the application permissions are given.

[image]

I am able to create the users with the above permissions.

**POST** **`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`**

```
Content-type: application/json

{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "kavxxxe",
  "mailNickname": "kavxx",
  "userPrincipalName": "xxx@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "xWxxxbWH-d"
  }
}
```

[image]

> Note: Make sure the permissions are given admin consent else this
> error may arise.

Refer : [Authorization_IdentityNotFound on Microsoft Graph API request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960959/authorization-identitynotfound-on-microsoft-graph-api-request)

**Edit:**

Admin consent can be granted from the portal itself if you are admin or while user login :

[image]

Comment: hi, I'm using the Admin account, so I have added the permissions but I did not have the - grant admin to consent. And also i have given all permissions. Can you give an example of an adminstrator account?

Comment: should it be multi-tenant app?

Comment: It need not be multi tenant , but if it is , then please make sure tenantId is given correctly and also  check for client ID and secret if they are correct. please check the edit in the answer , regarding admin consent.

Comment: should we want to use business account or personal account?

Comment: I have used microsoft account. It must  be work or school account .Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions